# Visual Studio intellisense icon meaning

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, icons, intellisense

What does mean following IntelliSense icon in `VS2013`:

[image]

Is there any reference for these type icons in `VS2013`?

Answer (score 6):

That icon appears to mean "Class And Method Reference (Ambiguous)."

The [Visual Studio Image Library download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) contains PDFs that list all of the icons and their meanings. The download I have linked to contains the image libraries for Visual Studio 2012 and up.

Comment: Link goes nowhere (2018 May). Searching the title will lead to...icons. Not necessarily the ones we're looking for.

Comment: Hmm, the link still works for me. Both https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library link to the same page I do.

Comment: You are correct. To the untrained eye, the page looks like a generic 404 landing page with an advert for a Surface Pro.  But the download is there; just have to read carefully.